# ASP.NET SecurityException

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I get the SecurityException when posting (form) to a specific aspx page. How do I get the real error when there is no stack trace or any useful information in the exception?

---

**Description:** The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy. To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

**Exception Details:** System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.

**Source Error:**

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace:**

[SecurityException: Request failed.]

Comment: You missed the most important part. What is your code?

Comment: @SonerGönül it's a relatively big project, so I can't really share the code. That's why I want to know how to get the "real" exception, because the one I get from ASP.NET is not really useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking [SecurityException.Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityexception.action.aspx) and [SecurityException.Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityexception.method.aspx).